# How to hide direct download link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am using WordPress.org to create my site where i am embedding direct download links from a ftp. I want to hide those links from the users. If user right click on the link, he will get the url to that file(resolved), if user go into developer console of browser then also my url to download is visible and even at the time of downloading (in downloads of browser) ,it shows the link from where it is downloading. How can i make it hide from the user?

Comment: try this plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/hide-real-download-path

Comment: I have tried this one, it blocks page where we mention it. I want to hide the real path of a link not want to block whole  page

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is **PHP Dispatching**. This basically means the file is served via PHP rather than as a redirect to the file path, meaning that the URL stays invisible to the user who is downloading the file.

Depending on your level of experience you can either use a plugin to achieve this effect such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-download-monitor/), or alternatively you can hook into Wordpress directly, although this would require some PHP knowledge.